# Custom SQL query for Datatable server side processing

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

I want to pass my own query to Datatable's query API but I don't know how to pass it.
Here is the `ssp.class.php` from the Datatables API. I want to modify it to meet up all the requirements for my project.

```
static function simple ( $request, $conn, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
    {
        // $bindings = array();
        $db = self::db( $conn );

        // Allow for a JSON string to be passed in
        // if (isset($request['json'])) {
        //  $request = json_decode($request['json'], true);
        // }

        // Build the SQL query string from the request
        // $limit = self::limit( $request, $columns );
        // $order = self::order( $request, $columns );
        // $where = self::filter( $request, $columns, $bindings );

        // Main query to actually get the data
        $data = self::sql_exec( $db,
            ""
        );

        // Data set length after filtering
        $resFilterLength = self::sql_exec( $db,
            ""
        );
        $recordsFiltered = $resFilterLength[0][0];

        // Total data set length
        $resTotalLength = self::sql_exec( $db,
            ""
        );
        $recordsTotal = $resTotalLength[0][0];

        /*
         * Output
         */
        return array(
            "draw"            => 1,
            "recordsTotal"    => intval( $recordsTotal ),
            "recordsFiltered" => intval( $recordsFiltered ),
            "data"            => self::data_output( $columns, $data )
        );
    }
```

How can I pass it through javascript? Here is my sample front-end code,

```
$('#tablee2').DataTable({
    lengthMenu: [[15, 25, 50, 100, -1],[15, 25, 50, 100, "All"],],
    order: $('#tablee').data('category') == "all_approved" ? [[4, 'asc']] : [[4, 'desc']],
    'bInfo': false,
    columnDefs: [
        { width: 300, targets: type == "ut" ? 10 : 9 }
    ],
    fixedColumns: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    "bStateSave": true,
        ajax: {
           url: '/api/datatable_query.php'
           type: 'POST'
           data: { 'custom_query':() => return 'SELECT ...' } // here is my custom query to be passed to the API
        }
    "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
        localStorage.setItem('offersDataTables', JSON.stringify(oData));
    },
    "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('offersDataTables'));
    }
})
```

So here is what my ajax returns

```
echo json_encode( 
    SSP::simple( $_POST['custom_query'], $dbDetails, $table, $primaryKey, $columns ) 
); // where I passed my own query
```

Will it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like that is hardly ever a good idea. You would have to perform so much validation on whatever SQL your backend gets passed, that you might as well just pass data in the first place, and create the query from it on the server side.